# Compare 2 arrays in VBA and write to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 excel sheets and i have to compare some values,this is the easy part. For this i used the following code :

```
Dim OldLabel() As String, size As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(3).Columns(1))

ReDim OldLabel(size)

j = 1

For i = 7 To size

   If (InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "[") > 0) Then
       OldLabel(j) = Cells(i, 1).Value
       j = j + 1
   End If

Next i

Dim NewLabel() As String, newSize As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer

newSize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(4).Columns(1))

ReDim NewLabel(newSize)

l = 1

For k = 7 To newSize
     If (InStr(Cells(k, 1).Value, "[") > 0) Then
       NewLabel(l) = Cells(k, 1).Value
       l = l + 1
   End If
Next k
```

After that i have to compare the values of the two arrays and check if they are the same and write them to another sheet. I have tried to following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
Dim cont As Integer
cont = 1

For i = 1 To size
    For k = 1 To newSize

        If (OldLabel(i) = NewLabel(k)) Then
            Sheet8.Activate
            Range("A1").Select
            Cells(cont, 1).Value = OldLabel(i)
            cont = cont + 1
        End If

    Next k

Next i
```

Comment: What is the problem? Program gives unexpected reuslts? Or here is some error/bug?

My first thought is: in loops, try using `LBound` and `UBound` functions, instead of hard-coded numbers.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to be working" isn't particularly helpful. Please post expected and actual output.

Comment: After i run the program i go back and check the sheet but there is no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the cases I recommend the use of data collections instead of arrays:

```
'Define data collections:
    Dim OldLabel As New Collection: Set OldLabel = New Collection
    Dim NewLabel As New Collection: Set NewLabel = New Collection
'Define data limits:
    Dim OldLimit As Integer
    OldLimit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(1).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim NewLimit As Integer
    NewLimit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Columns(1).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
'Define extra variables:
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 1
'Fill collections:
    For x = 1 To OldLimit
        If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 1).text, "[") > 0 Then
            OldLabel.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 1).text
        End If
    Next x
    For x = 1 To NewLimit
        If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 1).text, "[") > 0 Then
            NewLabel.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 1).text
        End If
    Next x
'Writer:
If OldLabel.Count > 0 And NewLabel.Count > 0 Then
    For x = 1 To OldLabel.Count
        For y = 1 To NewLabel.Count
            If OldLabel(x) = NewLabel(y) Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(counter, 1).FormulaR1C1 = OldLabel(x)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End If
```

Please note: a) You don't have to activate worksheets for your procedure; b) I named the worksheets and used that name to reference them; for some reasons, I prefer don't use sheets indexes; c) Check the fact you're only comparing cells with the "[" character in them; d) If any of the data columns is empty, the code will produce an error.

Comment: I tried to use your code but the result is the same,i still get no data in the required sheet,it's just blank

Comment: Can you show us your data columns? Or just a part of them? I tested on my machine and it worked fine...

Comment: Test the code yourself by placing the same text (with the "[" character in it) on a cell of each data column.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/ip305bjd7/
https://postimg.org/image/d9cvbklh7/

Comment: Ok. The highlight data (red) you show us, are not the same. It's only the same until the "[" character. Instead of `OldLabel.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 1).text` try `OldLabel.Add Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 1).text, InStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 1).text, "["))`. Adust it also for the NewLabel data:  `NewLabel.Add Left(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 1).text, InStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(x, 1).text, "["))`

Comment: Thank you,that seems to have done the job. I didn't notice the data was different

Comment: Just another thing: please verify that data with no "[" character in it will NOT be compared and this method will place duplicates on the output. If you want a different result, please let me know about it.

Comment: It's OK like this,I have tested and and it's fully functional right now .